# Error on loading borderPane in gluon project

Tags: java, javafx, gluon, javafxports, efxclipse

i'm developping an app in javaFX and recently had the necessity to make it cross-platform. I did some research, found the gluon plugin and I think it is a good way to re-use the code that is already done and don't just through it away and start something new.
In my javaFX project it compiles and run without any problem but when I try to compile the same code on the gluon project it returns this error:

```
    Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at com.resopark.MainApp.initRootLayout(MainApp.java:40)
    at com.resopark.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

here it is my MainApp:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Title");

        initRootLayout();
        showMainLayout();
    }

    public void initRootLayout() {
        try {
            // Load root layout from fxml file.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            // Show the scene containing the root layout.
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void showMainLayout(){
        try{
            // Load Technic Page.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/MainLayout.fxml"));
            AnchorPane mainLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            rootLayout.setCenter(mainLayout);

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Line 40 is : `rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();`

this is the build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b10'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.resopark.MainApp'

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = 'C:/Users/JSoares/AppData/Local/Android/sdk'
    }
}
```

I'm using eclipse in windows 10

Can anyone help me? thanks in advance. (sorry for my english)

Comment: `this.primaryStage = stage` instead of `this.primaryStage = primaryStage`

Comment: And if your IDE doesn't show a warning on that line, you might consider using a different IDE...

Comment: god, you're right, stupid mistake. Now it returns error when loading the rootLayout.